# Changing Visibility Of Texture View

Tags: android, textureview

How to change the visibility of `Texture View` by not changing alpha?

I want something like `getHolder.setformat` what is there is Surface View.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:visibility="invisible"` or `android:visibility="gone"` in xml layout file or do it programmatically `textView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`